# How to convert between LUFS and LU (EBU mode)

Tags: loudness

I want to use the [Digicheck](https://archiv.rme-audio.de/en/support/techinfo/digicheck.php) EBU R 128 meter to check that my material is *-14 LUFS integrated* (according to Spotify and Youtube specs). Thing is the target level of the Digicheck's meter is locked at -23 LUFS, which is displayed as 0 LU.

I want to target *-14 LUFS integrated* instead of *-23 LUFS integrated*, is that as simple as:

23-14=9

So the EBU meter (targeted at -23 LUFS) should read *9 LU*, and that will equal -14 LUFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0 LU` is defined by the EBU as `-23 LUFS` (https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/tech/tech3341.pdf) :

> The  scale  used  may  either  be  an  absolute  scale,  using  the
> unit  ‘LUFS’,  or  alternatively  the  zero   point may be mapped to
> some other value, such as the target loudness level (as in ITU-R
> BS.1771).  In the latter case the unit shall be ‘LU’, indicating a
> relative scale. For an ‘EBU Mode’ meter, the  target  loudness  level
> shall  be  −23.0 LUFS  =  0.0 LU  (as  defined  in  EBU R 128).  The
> ‘EBU Mode’  meter shall offer both the relative and the absolute
> scale.

If the digicheck tools conforms to this EBU mode, yes, `+9 LU` equals `-14 LUFS`.